# Granular access control for MediaWiki with LDAP

Tags: permissions, ldap, mediawiki, acl

My company has a MediaWiki setup which we are looking to make [partially] client accessible. Ideally each client would be able to see only their own page. Our wiki requires the user to be logged into view or edit, and we have the LDAP plugin ([This one,](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aLDAP_Authentication) specifically) so we can use our Active Directory credentials.

I see this question has come up before a few years ago, but I didn't see an question dealing with LDAP in particular. Can we manage a specific AD account if we give clients one on our domain for this purpose? Alternatively, is there a way to give clients a login directly into the wiki (sort of like logging locally into the computer, instead of the domain), that we could control the access rights of?

For reference: we are on MediaWiki version 1.19.1, PHP version 5.3.15, MySQL version 5.0.96-winx64, and the installation is running on Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 (IIS 7.5).

Thanks very much for the help!

Comment: Are you using the [Extension:LDAP_Authentication](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:LDAP_Authentication) extension for authentication?

Comment: Yes, that's the extension we're using.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11954817, http://stackoverflow.com/q/2676388

Answer (score 1):

You can use local accounts in addition to the LDAP accounts to log users in. You have to set [$wgLDAPUseLocal](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aLDAP_Authentication/Configuration_Options#Domain.2C_server_and_connection_configuration_options) to true in your LocalSettings.php. Basically, it adds another option to the domain drop down box on the login form that says "local". Users that want to log in with a local wiki account use that. I would also [disable account creation](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aPreventing_access#Restrict_account_creation)  on the wiki and create accounts manually for your clients.

Regardless of whether you use local accounts or AD accounts, for page-level access control, you would have to use one of [these extensions](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Category%3aPage_specific_user_rights_extensions). [Extension:AccessControl](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aAccessControl) seems to be a popular one.